# Is there any package using which I can use to navigate, avoiding obstacles and using robot_localisation's pose estimate on an unknown map

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am new to ROS. I have a p3dx robot and I am using it for outdoor navigation. I am using robot_localization package for pose estimate and localization. I have target points in GPS co-ordinates and want a shortest path algorithm like a -star to be implemented.I have sonar sensor to detect obstacles.
Is there any package using which I can navigate in an unknown map or area avoiding obstacles using the above data/configuration. I tried to analyze the Navigation stack but it requires cost map and other localization technique.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237379/is-there-any-package-using-which-i-can-use-to-navigate,-avoiding-obstacles-and-using-robot_localisation%27s-pose-estimate-on-an-unknown-map/) by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-17**:
The A-star algorithm and the navigation stack both depend on having a pre-built map. Without a pre-built map you will need to look at alternative algorithms for path planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [nav2d](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d) is the nav2d_operator, which is a purely reactive obstacle avoidance node, that can work without a global map. It uses a local costmap_2d internally, so you should check how to update that from sonar instead of laser range data.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-20**:
Thanks Sebastian, I will try it out.